# While loop will not find regex when checking for false value

Tags: perl, loops

I'm working on a script that gathers various specs of my companies computers, and stores it to a database. One section of the script searches through a file for the serial number of the credit card reader attached to the computer.

What I've found is that if I do not include a true/false check in the while condition, the regex will be matched, and I can break from there. That's fine, and it's what I'm going with. I do not understand though, why, when I change the while condition to include the true/false check, the regex is never matched.

Here is what I've found works

```
use v5.10;
use warnings;
use strict;

my $test;
open(my $fh, "<", "\\\\192.168.0.132\\storeman\\log\\2018-06-22.sls");
while(my $line = <$fh>){
    if($line =~ /unitid/i){
        $line =~ /(\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{3})/;
        $test = $1;
        last;
    }
};
say $test // "Nothing found";
```

On the other hand though, the follow does not work.

```
use v5.10;
use warnings;
use strict;

my $test;
open(my $fh, "<", "\\\\192.168.0.132\\storeman\\log\\2018-06-22.sls");
while(my $line = <$fh> && !$test){
    if($line =~ /unitid/i){
        $line =~ /(\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{3})/;
        $test = $1;
    }
};
say $test // "Nothing found";
```

Note that in each case, `$test` is undeclared until the regex finds a match. Also, even when declaring `$test` as an empty string, and trying `&& $test ne ""`, the regex still never matches.

I've debugged to the best of my abilities, and all I know is that when using `&& !$test`, the `if($line =~ /unitid/i)` is never found to be true.

What is it about the `&& !$test` that could cause the regex to never match, and thus the loop to never break, but instead run through the whole file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the return of `<$fh> && !$test` - this is a boolean context. Perl will return the last evaluated statement - in this case `!$test`. Which, since `$test` is undefined, is true, so 1.

Thus, `$line` would now contain 1. Which doesn't match your regex :)

If you wanted to, you could write `while( !$test && (my $line = <$fh>) ){`,
which would then behave as you seemed to expect. You could even do
`while( my $line = !$test && <$fh> )` - but I would not recommend that, as it is a bit confusing ( as you have noticed ;) ).

Comment: Thank you, this did work. I just want to make sure I understand you correctly. So, `while(my $line = <$fh> && !$test)` was implicitly evaluating like `while(my $line = (<$fh> && !$test))`?

Comment: Yes, this is due to operator precedence. If this were not the case, boolean statements would simply not work with assignments, consider `my $check = $true && $false` - if the brackets were different, `$check` would suddenly be true, and we'd be stumped :)

Comment: I was not aware of that, but that's a really nice tidbit to keep in mind!